# Altering a table column using change

Tags: mysql, sql

Altering a table column using `change` is not working but using `modify` the same query statement works fine.

**With change it fails:**

```
alter table users change name varchar(100);
```

**Error Code: 1064**. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(100)' at line 1    0.000 sec

**With Modify it works.**

```
alter table users modify name varchar(100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `CHANGE` then you have to specify a new name for the column, so the following should work:

```
alter table users change name newname varchar(100);
```

Look at the alter specification for `CHANGE`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `CHANGE` is different than `MODIFY`.
From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

```
CHANGE [COLUMN] old_col_name new_col_name column_definition
```

So, in your case, you should use:

```
alter table users change name name varchar(100);
```